Completeness of Eigenfunctions of Sturm-Liouville Operator
I have already seen a similar question about this topic, but unfortunately the answers I read didn't help me much. For my bachelor thesis in Mathematics (which is basically an introduction to Navier-Stokes equations) I have to write a chapter about Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem. I defined the Sturm-Liouville operator this way:
\begin{equation} 
    \mathcal{L}y=\frac{d}{dx} \left[ p(x) \frac{dy}{dx}\right]+q(x)y, \qquad y \in C^2([a,b]), \ \ \ p, q \in C([a, b]), \ \ \ p>0,
\end{equation}
with the following boundary-conditions:
\begin{equation} 
    a_1 y(a)+a_2 p(a) y'(a)=0 \qquad b_1 y(b)+b_2 p(b) y'(b)=0.
\end{equation}
If $p > 0$ and $r > 0$ over $[a, b]$ a Sturm-Liouville problem is called regular.
Let's fix $r \in C([a,b])$ a non-negative function. Our goal is to find complex numbers $\lambda$ such that the following equation
\begin{equation} 
    \mathcal{L}y + \lambda r(x) y=0 
\end{equation}
has non-trivial solutions. We call such $\lambda$ an eigenvalue for the Sturm-Liouville operator. I already proved the following statements: the eigenvalues of a regular Sturm-Liouville problem are real, eigenfunctions of different eigenvalues are orthogonal in $L^2_r([a,b])$, all eigenvalues are simple.
What I need to prove is that the set of all eigenfunctions for a regular Sturm-Liouville operator are an orthogonal basis of $L^2_r([a,b])$. What I cannot prove is completeness (and the fact that this set is infinite).
Could anyone give me any reference or give me a strategy to solve this?
Thank you in advance.

All-caps is taken as shouting here - please don't do that!

Have you looked the books by Ince or Guenther and Lee?

Gunther and Lee's book looks great! tysm @Aruralreader

I think the thesis is true iff r=1
